# Как разделить число на цифры в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3
Допустим:

'''a = int(input())'''

Нужно число в а разбить на цифры. Если а = 123, то нужно цифры отдельно засунуть в лист [1,2,3].
И чтобы числа внутри оставались как int а не str

Answer (score 3):

Здравствуйте вот ответ на ваш вопрос :)

```
a = int(input())
print(list(map(lambda x: int(x), str(a)))
```

Ответ данной программы будет:

```
[1, 2, 3] #При вводе 123
```

Либо:

```
a = [int(i) for i in input()]
print(a)
```

Ответ данной программы будет:

```
[1, 2, 3] #При вводе 123
```